# ibase_connect: local computer host, can't figure out working path

Tags: php, path, firebird

I may be dumb. Not sure yet.

Trying to do something that should be simple:

```
$database = '10.10.10.81:?????';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'pw';

$conn = ibase_connect($database, $username, $password);
if (!$conn)
{
    echo "Error while connecting: ".ibase_errmsg();
    exit();
}

echo 'workan';
```

We hit the error: connection rejected by remote interface. From another question here I read that this comes from various things: Could be a user/password problem, could be a host ($database) problem, something else that I forget.

I believe my host string is terribly wrong and can't figure out how I should be going about this. Perhaps my google-fu is not up to par.

Trying to get to
E:\fishbowl\database\data\base.fdb
on 10.10.10.81, a separate local computer

Tried a bunch of combinations but can't seem to make anything work.

Edit: Just a heads up, this is a firebird database. Not sure if that changes things

Comment: I'm not 100% and I can't verify (so I won't officially answer), but give this a try: `$database = '10.10.10.81:E:\\fishbowl\\database\\data\\base.fdb';`

Comment: And it's a good question; Google didn't turn up with much at all for connecting to a remote Windows location

Comment: Hmm, I tried similar, just one slash each previously. Your try didn't work sadly. Could it possibly be that the problem is originating from something else?

Comment: It could be; unfortunately, this is well outside my area of expertise. Best of luck though!

Comment: Is E:\ an actual drive on the local computer (and not a mapped network drive), and is Firebird configured to allow access to that path? Specifically look at firebird.conf, configoption `DatabaseAccess`; if it is `None` then you can only use an alias, if it is `Restrict`, then you can only access paths that have a prefix that is listed after `Restrict`

Comment: And is Firebird running on port 3050 on `10.10.10.81`, and accepting external connections?

Comment: I already opened port 3050 (it has a different error for when 3050 isn't opened and cleared that up)

I'm looking into the other one now (by local computer I assume you mean 10.10.10.81 having the E:\ drive, which it does)

Comment: DatabaseAccess = Full is currently set. I have restarted the service and tried again with no luck; same error.

Would you agree, mark, that the host string glaciesofpacis gave would be the correct format?

Comment: That database string looks ok to me.

Comment: What happens if you telnet 10.10.10.81 3050 . Do you get connected? I ask that because the _connectoin rejected_ error means you can't connect to that port.

Comment: Interesting. Telnet doesn't do anything (just sits there, blank cmd window after starting). I had to enable telnet on both this computer and the server, so not sure if a telnet response is running properly on the server. Either way, I've opened 3050 completely on TCP/UPD in firewall w/ advanced security - so either telnet is wrong or I missed something --? It should be open

Comment: If you really want to connect to database, which is on some windows share (from perspective of the server), you can try to subst your share to a local drive letter. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, it should look like this:

`localhost/10095:C:/Data/SKLADFD.FDB`.

See how port (in this case 10095) is specified.

In your case:

`10.10.10.81/3050:E:/fishbowl/database/data/base.fdb`

Path to the file must be local file on server, not windows share on connecting machine.

Comment: This answers the original question, though I will note that I was still unable to get it to work, despite opening ports. Between this and Glacies' example, I feel I can accept this answer as it shows HOW it should be done, something google wasn't really bringing any examples up on.